# Implementation of checkboxes using Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Am trying to create a TodoList where a user clicks a checkbox to tick checked when complete is true , but am not understanding the concept with checkboxes. just recently started learning django , the below code is what l have come up with.

Model Code

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class List(models.Model):
    list_title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    list_context = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.list_title
```

view code

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import List

# Create your views here.

def index(Request):
    list_items = List.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
    list_ticked =[]
    if Request.method == "Post":
        list_ticked = Request.Post.getlist('items')
        if list_ticked== True:
          complete = True  
    context = {
        'list_items':list_items,
        'list_ticked':list_ticked,
    }

    template = 'TodoList/index.html'

    return render (Request,template,context)
```

Html Code

```
<ul class="list-group mb-0">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    {%if list_items%}
                    {%for item in list_items %}
                  <li
                    class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center border-start-0 border-top-0 border-end-0 border-bottom rounded-0 mb-2"> 
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                      <input class="form-check-input me-2" type="checkbox" value="{{item.id}}" id="item {{forloop.counter}}" name="list_ticked =[]" />
                      {{item.list_context}}
                    </div>
                    <a href="#!" data-mdb-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove item">
                      <i class="fas fa-times text-primary"></i>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  {%endfor%}
                  {%else%}
                  <p>No list available</p>
                  {%endif%}
                </form>
                </ul> <ul class="list-group mb-0">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    {%if list_items%}
                    {%for item in list_items %}
                  <li
                    class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center border-start-0 border-top-0 border-end-0 border-bottom rounded-0 mb-2"> 
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                      <input class="form-check-input me-2" type="checkbox" value="{{item.id}}" id="item {{forloop.counter}}" name="item" />
                      {{item.list_context}}
                    </div>
                    <a href="#!" data-mdb-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove item">
                      <i class="fas fa-times text-primary"></i>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  {%endfor%}
                  {%else%}
                  <p>No list available</p>
                  {%endif%}
                </form>
                </ul>
```

To be more helpful can you explain the concept in checkboxes how they work

Answer (score 0):

1. you have name the list in html 'item' but in views u use items, pay attention that u must name all the checklist options the same, and u refer to it in views.

I will give you an example: for check input field complete :
personally I like using django forms with crispy forms:

```
#forms.py
 complete = forms.BooleanField(required=True, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check-input'}),
                                    label=_(
                                        'completed?'))
```

```
#models.py
complete = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=False, default=False)
```

```
# some-template.html
{{ form.complete|as_crispy_field }}
```

so in ur case: if you wanna do something specifically when user press on it: you must handle the views.py post method

```
#views.py
if request.method == 'POST':
    item = request.POST.getlist('item')
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically in HTML When a checkbox is checked, it sends a value (usually "on" or "true") as part of the form submission. If it's unchecked, it doesn't send any value.
so if you would like to change the complete field in your django app when a checkbox is checked you will first need to give every checkbox a unique name and value corresponding to the item's ID in your database.
so in this case when the form is submitted, you need to iterate through the list of checked items and update their "complete" field in your database.
so your django view should look like something like this:

```
def index(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    # Get the list of item IDs that were checked
    checked_items_ids = request.POST.getlist('item')
    for item_id in checked_items_ids:
        item = List.objects.get(pk=item_id)
        item.complete = True
        item.save()
    return redirect('index')
```